# codeigniter multiple where clause is not working

Tags: database, codeigniter

My controller (I want to select records based on some conditions) :

```
public function promotion()
{
    if(!$this->user_permission->check_permission())return;

        $data['startDate'] = $this->input->post('input_date_from');
        $data['endDate'] = $this->input->post('input_date_to');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');

    var_dump($email);
    var_dump($data['startDate']);
    var_dump($data['endDate']);

    $this->db->select('a.booking_id as booking_id, a.from_email as from_email, a.booking_date as booking_date, a.status as status, b.vendor_airway_bill as awb, b.tariff as tariff');
    $this->db->where('from_email', $email);
    $this->db->where('booking_date >=', date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data['startDate'])));
    $this->db->where('booking_date <=', date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data['endDate'])));
    $this->db->where('status = 1');
    $this->db->or_where('status = 2');
    $this->db->from('booking as a');
    $this->db->join('shipment as b','a.booking_id = b.booking_id','left');      
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data['result'] = $query->result_array();

    $this->template->render('admin/promotion',$data,'admin');

}
```

My view (I want to show booking shipment based on `from_email` from the user input. I set the table to `display:none`, and when the user input something in `from_email` input then click `view`, it shows the datatable) :

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="cashback">
    User Email :
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    Booking Date :
    <div id="daterange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; display:inline">
     <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="input_date_from" id="input_date_from" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="input_date_to" id="input_date_to" value="">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="promotion();">View
   </button>
</form>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="promotion" style="display:none">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>BookingDate</th>
                <th>UserEmail</th>
                <th>AirwayBill</th>
                <th>Tariff</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($result as $r) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $r['booking_date'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $r['from_email'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $r['awb'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $r['tariff'];?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $r['status'];?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<template block="custom_js">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2.1.24/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('asset/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">base_url='<?php echo base_url()?>'</script>
<script>
    <?php if(isset($startDate) && isset($endDate)): ?>
      var startDate = '<?php echo $startDate ?>';
      var endDate   = '<?php echo $endDate ?>';
    <?php endif; ?>

$(function() {
    $('#promotion').DataTable();

    var start = typeof(startDate) === 'string' ? moment(startDate) : moment().startOf('month');
    var end = typeof(endDate) === 'string' ? moment(endDate) : moment();
    $('#input_date_from').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    $('#input_date_to').val(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));


    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#daterange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#daterange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

    $('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $('#input_date_from').val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#input_date_to').val(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    });

});

function promotion() {

    input_date_to = $('#input_date_to').val();
    input_date_from = $('#input_date_from').val();
    email = $('#email').val();

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/promotion')?>",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: {email: email, input_date_from: input_date_from, input_date_to: input_date_to},
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#promotion').show();
            console.log(email);
            console.log(input_date_from);
            console.log(input_date_to);
        }
    })
}

</script>
```

I try to filter data based on `from_email`, `date_range_from` and `date_range_to`. When I `var_dump` the input post, it showing the value as I expected, but it didn't run the `this->db->where('from_email',$email)`, so I get all result..

Comment: What error message that SQL statement produce?

Comment: It all looks good to me. What happens if you take off the or_where statement? Another thing to try is to run the query but use get_compiled_select rather than get and then output the query string to see what is going on.  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::get_compiled_insert

Comment: i see no error @ZamronyP.Juhara

Comment: If i take off the `or_` it gives me no result @PaulD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]. Use `where_in()` instead of `or_where`

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
$this->db->where('status = 1');
$this->db->or_where('status = 2');
```

into something like:

```
$this->db->where('(status = 1 OR status = 2)');
```

note parenthesis is important to make `OR` operator get higher presedence than `AND` operator. Also turn on your query log and check what actual SQL is sent to database server to better understand why.

Comment: i don't understand why it gives me no result :(

Comment: i wonder if it has something to do with jquery datatable. because when the table load, it shows all the result regardless of which email is. But im not really sure about this

Comment: This Solved my problem. Thank you!